# Service exception while integrating Jersey - Grizzly with Spring 3

Tags: spring, jersey, grizzly

I am trying to bring up a REST Server(without UI) using jersey + grizzly. I am attempting to use spring.

My github project link: https://github.com/seshumadhav/java-projects/tree/master/grizzlySpringJersey

When I run 'MyServer', and hit a url like `http://localhost:3388/smc/time`, I am banged with a ServletHandler.doServletService 'java.lang.NoSuchMethodError' exception. Full server log below

Can someone help me understand reason behind this, and how to get this fixed ?

```
Dec 26, 2013 5:53:21 PM org.glassfish.grizzly.servlet.WebappContext deploy
INFO: Starting application [DEMO REST Server WebappContext] ...
Dec 26, 2013 5:53:21 PM org.glassfish.grizzly.servlet.WebappContext log
INFO: [DEMO REST Server WebappContext] Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext
Dec 26, 2013 5:53:21 PM org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader initWebApplicationContext
INFO: Root WebApplicationContext: initialization started
Dec 26, 2013 5:53:21 PM org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext prepareRefresh
INFO: Refreshing Root WebApplicationContext: startup date [Thu Dec 26 17:53:21 IST 2013]; root of context hierarchy
Dec 26, 2013 5:53:21 PM org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader loadBeanDefinitions
INFO: Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [applicationContext.xml]
Dec 26, 2013 5:53:21 PM org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory preInstantiateSingletons
INFO: Pre-instantiating singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@192d5cf3: defining beans [resourceFoo,springRunner,myBean,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalConfigurationAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalAutowiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalRequiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalCommonAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.importAwareProcessor]; root of factory hierarchy
Dec 26, 2013 5:53:21 PM org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader initWebApplicationContext
INFO: Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 377 ms
Dec 26, 2013 5:53:21 PM com.sun.jersey.spi.spring.container.servlet.SpringServlet getContext
INFO: Using default applicationContext
Dec 26, 2013 5:53:21 PM com.sun.jersey.spi.spring.container.SpringComponentProviderFactory registerSpringBeans
INFO: Registering Spring bean, resourceFoo, of type com.demo.web.ResourceFoo as a root resource class
Dec 26, 2013 5:53:21 PM com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl _initiate
INFO: Initiating Jersey application, version 'Jersey: 1.17.1 02/28/2013 12:47 PM'
Dec 26, 2013 5:53:22 PM org.glassfish.grizzly.servlet.WebappContext initServlets
INFO: [DEMO REST Server WebappContext] Servlet [com.sun.jersey.spi.spring.container.servlet.SpringServlet] registered for url pattern(s) [[/*]].
Dec 26, 2013 5:53:22 PM org.glassfish.grizzly.servlet.WebappContext deploy
INFO: Application [DEMO REST Server WebappContext] is ready to service requests.  Root: [/].
Dec 26, 2013 5:53:22 PM org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.NetworkListener start
INFO: Started listener bound to [localhost:3388]
Dec 26, 2013 5:53:22 PM org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServer start
INFO: [HttpServer] Started.
In order to test the server please try the following urls:
http://localhost:3388/smc/time to see time for smc
http://localhost:3388/bsv/time to see time for bsv
Press enter to stop the server...
Dec 26, 2013 5:53:28 PM org.glassfish.grizzly.servlet.ServletHandler doServletService
SEVERE: service exception:
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.Request.createInputStream()Lorg/glassfish/grizzly/http/io/NIOInputStream;
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.servlet.ServletInputStreamImpl.initialize(ServletInputStreamImpl.java:89)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.servlet.HttpServletRequestImpl.initialize(HttpServletRequestImpl.java:208)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.servlet.ServletHandler.doServletService(ServletHandler.java:212)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.servlet.ServletHandler.service(ServletHandler.java:189)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:164)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandlerChain.service(HttpHandlerChain.java:196)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:164)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:175)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:265)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:200)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:134)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:78)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:815)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:115)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:55)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:135)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:567)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:547)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)

Dec 26, 2013 5:53:28 PM org.glassfish.grizzly.servlet.ServletHandler doServletService
SEVERE: service exception:
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.Request.createInputStream()Lorg/glassfish/grizzly/http/io/NIOInputStream;
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.servlet.ServletInputStreamImpl.initialize(ServletInputStreamImpl.java:89)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.servlet.HttpServletRequestImpl.initialize(HttpServletRequestImpl.java:208)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.servlet.ServletHandler.doServletService(ServletHandler.java:212)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.servlet.ServletHandler.service(ServletHandler.java:189)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:164)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandlerChain.service(HttpHandlerChain.java:196)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:164)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:175)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:265)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:200)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:134)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:78)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:815)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:115)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:55)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:135)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:567)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:547)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
```

Related other question:
Can someone correct If I am using correct/latest maven dependencies

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The original pom seems to be broken.

You can fix it by changing some dependencies as follows:

Demote `grizzly-http-servlet` from `2.3.4` to `2.2.16`

This way it's compatible with the other grizzly (transitive) dependencies:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.grizzly</groupId>
    <artifactId>grizzly-http-servlet</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.16</version>
</dependency>
```

Also, demote the Servlet API spec dependency from `3.1.0` to `3.0.1`

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Ur solution worked for me. It is fixed. I updated code on github. Curious to know: How did you realize the problem was with versions? I m trying to understand this, so that I can use this understanding for any future problems ?

Comment: First cloned the project, built it and opened `ServletInputStreamImpl` in the IDE, noticed the compilation error, looked at the pom, seen the version mismatch for `grizzly-http-servlet`, changed it's version. Now it was lacking to implement a new method from servlet-api 3.1, changed the servlet-api version as well. That's it